# Facebook v2 api: Are page id and personal profile id unique?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the Facebook v2 graph api, I can get my user id using `/me` and the ids of the pages I manage using `/me/accounts/`.

Are these 2 types of ids guaranteed to be different? I would assume so but cannot find any documentation to support.

EDIT

To be clear, I'm asking if there can be a User ID that is the same as a Page ID.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they are different and unique, it´s an ID. The whole point of IDs is that they are unique. Just be aware that you will get an "App Scoped ID" for user profiles, and the "real ID" for pages.